# Why output of int 070 is 56 in C program?

Tags: c, int, decimal, octal

Can you explain it? Why it given 56 value as output?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    int x = 070;
    printf("%d", x);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: If the language was being designed these days, I wonder if they'd still use the `0` prefix for octal? I think my favored alternative would be `0k`/`0K`. (`0o` or `0O` would be too confusing.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any integer literal (integer constant) starting with `0` is an [octal representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.4.1, *Integer constants*

> `octal-constant:`
>
> 0
>  *octal-constant* *octal-digit*

and

> *octal-digit*: one of
>
> ```
>   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
> ```

and, as per chapter §7.21.6.1, for `%d` format specifier with `printf()`, (*emphasis mine*)

> `d,i` The `int` argument is converted to signed **decimal** [...]

Thereby, [octal 70 == decimal 56](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/octal-to-decimal.htm).

Comment: Thanks @FUZxxl for the edit. :)